# convert big int number into array of single digit

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to store the single digit of integer value to an array by first converting it into string and then using 'split()' method to store it inside an array but looks like in JavaScript this works only for small integers up to 15 digits, for more than 15 digits I am getting '2.1321321381211322e+27' exponential and it cannot be moved inside an array by converting first into string and by using split. Then it looks like
2
.
6
5
2
5
2
8
5
9
8
1
2
1
9
1
0
3
e
+
3
2

Can Anyone tell me how to deal with big numbers.

My code

```
const myNum = 2132132138121132132145463636;
let myNumArray = ((myNum.toString()).split(''));
console.log(myNumArray);    //2 . 6 5 2 5 2 8 5 9 8 1 2 1 9 1 0 3 e + 3 2
```

Comment: Where did you get this big number? JavaScript cannot preserve such a big number without losing its percision. If you're typing this number by hand, just make it a string, or a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: @Hao Wu, I am getting this number after some calculations which includes square and multiplication of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's calculated, try calculate it with [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
const myNum = 1337n * 69n ** 42n;
let myNumArray = myNum.toString().split('');
console.log(myNumArray);
```